# Creating a new variable from existing variables with a condition

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new variable from my existing variables and that it satisfies a condition.

```
  startyear endyear ongoingasofyear imposition
  (dbl)   (dbl)           (dbl)      (dbl)
1      1945    1947              NA          1
2      1946    1949              NA          1
3      1946    1993              NA          1
4      1946    1960              NA          1
5      1946    1946              NA          1
6      1946      NA            1946          1
```

I want to create a variable called sanctions_period. I want it to range from startyear - endyear when those are available and then range from startyear - ongoing if endyear is NA and ongoingasofyear is not NA.

This is what it should look like:

```
      startyear endyear ongoingasofyear imposition sanctions_period
  (dbl)   (dbl)           (dbl)      (dbl)
1      1945    1947              NA          1     1945-1947
2      1946    1949              NA          1     1946-1949
3      1946    1993              NA          1     1946-1993
4      1946    1960              NA          1     1946-1960
5      1946    1946              NA          1     1946-1946
6      1946      NA            1946          1     1946-ongoing
```

How might i go about doing this? I have tried different setups with ifelse, but so far haven't been successful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we are using the 'tbl_df', one option with the `dplyr` would be to create the variable using `mutate` by `paste`ing the columns together and an `ifelse` condition can be used to account for the NA elements in 'endyear'.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>%
     mutate(sanctions_period = ifelse(is.na(endyear) & !is.na(ongoingasofyear), 
         paste(startyear, "ongoing", sep="-"), paste(startyear, endyear, sep="-")))
#     startyear endyear ongoingasofyear imposition sanctions_period
#1      1945    1947              NA          1        1945-1947
#2      1946    1949              NA          1        1946-1949
#3      1946    1993              NA          1        1946-1993
#4      1946    1960              NA          1        1946-1960
#5      1946    1946              NA          1        1946-1946
#6      1946      NA            1946          1     1946-ongoing
```

Comment: How could i add that when both endyear and ongoingasofyear are NA then to remove that?

Comment: @jo.magi  Then we could first subset the dataset before creating the column. i.e. `df1 %>% filter(!(is.na(endyear) & is.na(ongoingasofyear)) %>% mutate(sanctions_period = if_else(is.na(endyear) & !is.na(ongoingasofyear), paste(startyear, "ongoing", sep="-"), paste(startyear, endyear, sep= "-")))`